# how to order columns by names containing special symbols R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have dataframe below:

```
df <- data.frame(aa = rep(1,4),
                ae = rep(2,4),
                dd = rep(3,4),
                `aa%` = rep(11,4),
                `ae%` = rep(22,4),
                `dd%` = rep(33,4))

  aa ae dd aa. ae. dd.
1  1  2  3  11  22  33
2  1  2  3  11  22  33
3  1  2  3  11  22  33
4  1  2  3  11  22  33
```

I want to order the columns to become like

```
  aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

so I did

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)
df %>%
  select(1, mixedorder(names(.)[-1]))
```

but this gives

```
  aa dd aa. ae ae.
1  1  3  11  2  22
2  1  3  11  2  22
3  1  3  11  2  22
4  1  3  11  2  22
```

How can I get the output with desired order of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mixedsort` instead of `mixedorder`

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(mixedsort(names(.)))
   aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

---

The issue with `mixedorder` by removing the first column is that it returns an index starting from 1, which needs to start from 2 i.e. add 1

```
df %>%
   select(1, mixedorder(names(.)[-1])+1)
  aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I believe there is something I can not figure out about dplyr functions. like this one. it works perfectly on this laptop and not working on another. on my other machine it is doing anything to the df! aahhh frustrating!

Comment: @Mathica Please check if the `packageVersion('dplyr')` are same.  Also, `select` is one function which can be present in multiple packages.  Perhaps, it got masked by any other package functions?  Use `dplyr::select` explicitly in that case.  Note that you have to assign the output to an object i.e. `df <- df%>% select(mixedsort(names(.)))` to update the same object or to a new object i.e. `dfsub <- df%>% select(mixedsort(names(.)))`

Comment: both machines have dplyr 1.0.8 installed. I used dplyr:: and gtools:: , and I assigned it to a new object. is there anything else I can check. the machine on which my df is not changed is using RstudioServer. could it be somehow the reason?

Comment: @Mathica Can you try on a fresh R session after loading only `library(dplyr)` and `library(gtools)`

Comment: :( . still same result. This is not the first time I am facing this issue. I once asked another question here and the answers I got worked perfectly here but not on Rstudioserver machine. which made me write it so ugly in base R.

Comment: @Mathica Does it have the same version for `gtools`?  Probably, it could be an env issue.  Are the `R` versions same in both?  It is possible that an older R version could impact the dependency package of dplyr especially `tidyselect`

Comment: Rversion on good machine is 4.1.2 and on bad machine is 4.1.3. Thank you for pointing this out! I go ckeck if it is the R version that causes this!

Comment: @Mathica I tested on `R 4.2.0` which is a higher version compared to yours with `packageVersion('tidyselect')#
[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: Although I still do not know how to solve it!! I found out what the problem is! On my bad Machine I am dynamically reading data from a server( no .csv file or such). I saved 100 rows of that data as a .csv to transfer to my good machine to try your code on it. Now I ran the code on my bad machine but on .csv data ( and not the data which comes live from the server ) . It worked! sighhh but I have to find a way to make this work for my live server data too . Thank you Akrun! You are a priceless asset on this website. I have learnt ALOT from you so far! @akrun

Comment: @Mathica It is possible that your bad machine column names will be different compared to your good ones.  because you are reading with `read.csv` and if you don't use `check.names = FALSE`, it changes the column names with unusual characters by appending the `.` etc where as in the other one, the `%` remains

Comment: Oh no! I added check.name=F and my good machine in doing what my bad machine was doing.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr` we could:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(order(colnames(df)))
```

```
  aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(sort(names(.)))

#>   aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
#> 1  1  11  2  22  3  33
#> 2  1  11  2  22  3  33
#> 3  1  11  2  22  3  33
#> 4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

Answer (score 2):

A simplier way to go:

```
 df[,order(colnames(df))] 

  aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(sort(tidyselect::peek_vars()))
```

Output:

```
  aa aa. ae ae. dd dd.
1  1  11  2  22  3  33
2  1  11  2  22  3  33
3  1  11  2  22  3  33
4  1  11  2  22  3  33
```